# Github API add user to organization

Tags: github-api, octokit

I'm struggling with [add-or-update-organization-membership](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-or-update-organization-membership) endpoint. I use Octokit and I'm authenticated via OAuth as organization owner and when I try to invite somebody I receive:

`Octokit::Forbidden: PUT https://api.github.com/orgs/<org name>/memberships/<user login>: 403 - You must be an admin to add or update an organization membership. // See: https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-or-update-organization-membership`

I have following OAuth scopes: `"user,user:repo,write:org,read:org"`.

Answer (score 2):

Sigh... I needed `admin:org` scope.

Comment: There seems to be limitation of 50 additions per 24 hours. Did you had a work around for that ? or you never had a use case for more than 50 invitations per 24 hours